# ¿De qué manera puedo unir TODA la información de un Objeto?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función `whatIsInAName(collection)` que imprime a la consola (como string) cada llave y propiedad de cada objeto que existe en `collection`:

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection) {
 
  for (obj in collection){
 for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(collection[obj])) {
    console.log(key + value)
        }}
}

console.log(whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null });

// Resultado:

VM2094:9 firstRomeo
VM2094:9 lastMontague
VM2094:9 firstMercutio
VM2094:9 lastnull
VM2094:9 firstTybalt
VM2094:9 lastCapulet
```

Sin embargo me gustaría que imprimiese toda la información junta de cada objeto, es decir:

```
// Resultado:

firstRomeolastMontague 
firstMercutiolastnull
firstTybaltlastCapulet
```

Cómo se puede hacer? (si se puede)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection) {
 
    for (obj in collection){
        var salida = '';
    
        for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(collection[obj])) {
           salida += key + value;
        }
        
        console.log(salida);
    }
}

whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }]);
```

Jugando un poco con los bucles `for` se puede lograr de una manera simple. En vez de hacerle un `console.log()` a cada `clave->valor` del objeto, lo que puedes hacer es guardarlo en una variable acumulativa para hacerle el `console.log` a esa variable al finalizar el bucle interior.

Esto funciona porque el primer bucle recorre los objetos y el segundo las propiedades de cada objeto.

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción que tienes es utilizar directamente un join sobre el `Object.entries` (y quitar las comas que te genera).

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection) { 
     for (obj in collection){
console.log(Object.entries(collection[obj]).join("").replace(",","").replace(",",""));
    }
}

whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }]);
```